# Simultaneous equations with four unknowns?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find the values of x and y which satisfy the following equations:

$x^2+xy$ = $\dfrac{a(a+b)}2$, $xy+y^2$ = $\dfrac{a(a-b)}2$

Where $a≠0$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried to manipulate the equations to obtain four equations but ended up finding that x=y and a=b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it
$$x^2+xy= \dfrac{a(a+b)}2\tag 1$$ $$xy+y^2 = \dfrac{a(a-b)}2\tag 2$$

Fom $(1)$
$$y=\dfrac{a(a+b)}{2x}-x\tag 3$$ Plug this in $(2)$ and simplify to get
$$\frac{a^4+2 a^3 b+a^2 b^2}{4 x^2}=a^2\implies x^2=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2\implies x=???$$

Then, use $(3)$ to get $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding both equations:
$$x^2+2xy+y^2=a^2$$
$$(x+y)^2=a^2$$

Substructing the second from the first:
$$x^2-y^2=ab$$
$$(x-y)(x+y)=ab$$

Continue from here...

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+xy=a(a+b)/2~~~(1), y^2+xy=a(a-b)/2~~~(2)$
Adding (1) and (2) we get $$(x+y)^2=a \implies x+y= \pm \sqrt{a}~~~(3)$$
From (1) and (3) we get $$x=\pm \sqrt{a}~(a+b)/2$$
From (2) and (3) we get $$y=\pm \sqrt{a}~(a-b)/2$$